# How to put files in SFTP using PHP yii2

Tags: php, yii2, sftp, yii2-advanced-app

I want to put these files to my **SFTP** server

```
Array
(
    [0] => admin/web/uploads/invoice/21-1623165946--invoice.pdf
    [1] => admin/web/uploads/invoice/4-1623166165--invoice.pdf
    [2] => admin/web/uploads/invoice-csv/Created-2021-06-15_05-34-22.csv
)
```

with the all permissions `eg.0777` in the folder
the folder structure will be like this

```
root
|--test
|--|--(create a directory current date in Y-m-d format and give all permission eg.0777) 
|--|--|--inside that folder the list of files must be uploaded
```

I have **configured my project** and installed `PHP yii2 extension` from [yii2-gftp](https://github.com/hguenot/yii2-gftp) and have done all the things as per **installation guide**

I have searched everywhere and haven't find a single demo code for this, have anyone faced this kind of problem please let me know how you solved this.

Comment: There’s a `put` method, and the parameters are documented inside the code: https://github.com/hguenot/yii2-gftp/blob/31fb06f7ab5d921dca30fc03399c43910b5a5a32/drivers/RemoteDriver.php#L100

Comment: @CBroe I'm getting this error:
Exception &#039;TypeError&#039; with message &#039;Argument 3 passed to gftp\FtpComponent::put() must be of the type int, string given, called in E:\wamp64\www\application\backend\controllers\LoadInformationController.php on line 464&#039; 

in E:\wamp64\www\application\vendor\hguenot\yii2-gftp\FtpComponent.php:307

Answer (score 1):

In the example they put

```
$gftp->put($tmp_file,$filename,"FTP_ASCII", true)
```

but it should be:

```
$gftp->put($tmp_file,$filename,FTP_ASCII, true)
```

that will get rid of your current error message